# Is there an implicit unlift of total functions in Scala when `PartialFunction` is required?

Tags: scala

I'm a little baffled by the error

```
[error]  found   : A => B
[error]  required: PartialFunction[A,B]
```

I can fix it by wrapping the function I'm using in `Function.unlift(x => Some(...))` but this seems like something I would have expected to be implicit given [the doc's definition](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.3/scala/PartialFunction.html) of "A partial function of type PartialFunction[A, B] is a unary function where the domain does not **necessarily** include all values of type A".

With the word "necessarily", this definition seems to explicitly include a function `A => B` being a `PartialFunction[A, B]`. Am I mis-reading this, or missing something else?

To add to my confusion, while I get this error in my code with `Throwable` and `com.twitter.util.Future[com.twitter.finagle.http.Response]`, I cannot reproduce it with [a simpler example](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/TX6j0fafTk671NkrwaiVSA).

Answer (score 1):

`PartialFunction does not necessarily include all values of type A` this means you can only handle the **target value** without the other values. like the **pattern match**.

Example 1:

```
List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5).collect({
    case x if x % 2 == 0 => x + 1
})
```

In the above code snippet, we only want to handle the **even** numbers and **plus** 1. if there is no `PartialFunction`, we will need to `filter` even numbers firstly and `map` again.

Example 2:

```
List(1, 2, "one", "two").collect({
    case x: String => x + 1
})
```

In the Example 2, we only want to handle the **String** type values in the list, so `PartialFunction` also can used to **match** the type.

So if you want to `implicit` to convert `Function` to `PartialFunction`, I think you can define implicit method like:

```
  implicit def convertFunctionToPartialFunction[A, B](f: A => Option[B]) = {
    Function.unlift(f)
  }
  val a: Int => Option[Int] = (x: Int) => {
    if (x % 2 == 0) {
      Some(x + 1)
    } else None
  }

  val res = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5).collect(a)
```

but seems `a` `Function` is ugly...

Answer (score 1):

`PartialFunction[A, B]` is a subtype of `A => B`. In particular, it has the method `isDefinedAt` which `A => B` doesn't have. So where a `PartialFunction` is expected, a normal function can't be used.

Your "simpler example" does the opposite: it passes a `PartialFunction` to something that expects a function. This direction works fine.

Instead of messing around with `Function.unlift`, you can just use

```
{ case x => f(x) }
```

(since `PartialFunction` is the expected type in your case). There's also [`PartialFunction(f)`, but it's deprecated since 2.12.5](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.5/scala/PartialFunction$.html#apply[A,B](f:A=%3EB):PartialFunction[A,B]).